# Is redundancy in a database ever acceptable or is it always a sign of bad design?

Tags: database

I have two tables:

- `auth` contains authentication information
- `users` contains user profile information

`auth` has a `username` column. This serves as both a login credential and as part of the user's profile URL (e.g. `example.com/profiles/username`).

When retrieving a list of users, their username is required to make the URL to their profile. Currently, I query the `users` table and join the `auth` table to get this info. However, that join can be avoided if `username` is also a column in `users`, making two identical columns in two different tables.

I don't like the idea of a duplicate column, but one less join is always good. Is this a sign that the database schema (or something else) needs to be reworked, or is this an example of a case where redundancy is acceptable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normalizing your schema (i.e. removing redundancy) is not designed to address efficiency in time, but rather a) efficiency in space (by eliminating duplicate copies of data) and b) consistency (by not storing the same information in multiple places, you do not run the risk of having them not agree).  From that perspective, having to use a join is the cost of these other benefits.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite difficult to give you good answer without wider picture of your application. Personally I do not think it is good idea to duplicate information such as user name.

When you make such design decisions you should consider system maintenance / future developments etc. A few points:

- Is username going to be changed by a users in the future? With duplicated columns, simple update becomes sometimes quite challenging task to update multi tables (if you duplicate information once, other teams can follow that example and do it again and again).
- If your system is developed or maintained by different teams (which don't necessary know your system well enough) they may miss duplicates if some tables and cause data inconsistency.

Hope that will help.

Answer (score 1):

"One less join is always good".  I take issue with that.  Databases are designed for joining tables together.  The extra join would typically require work such as:

1. Locating the page containing the key in the index of the second table.  Very fast, since the index should be in memory.
2. Retrieving in the second table with the value.
3. Processing the data on the page.

Although this may sound like a lot of work, it is really at most a few milliseconds of effort.

If the second table fits in memory -- or you include the user name field in the index so the second read is not necessary -- then this all happens quite fast.  Admittedly, if you are trying to get 5,000 transactions per second out of mediocre hardware, then you might care.  For most purposes, the extra few milliseconds (at the most!) are not expensive.

What does this extra work buy you?  It makes sure that the user name is the most recent user name, if that has been changed.

You may have other requirements for your application.  Performance may be critical, in which case denormalizing the data may be useful (although a composite index would probably be pretty close performance-wise).  You may be in a memory-limited environment, in which case having all user data load in a single page read might be important.  User names may never change, in which case you might consider having the user name be the primary key on the table.  That is, there are situations where denormalizing would be a serious option.

There are definitely other cases as well.  Just about all analysis works from denormalized data structures, for instance.

Comment: Note that, depending on how your indexes are set up, it may not be necessary to perform I/O to get the username from the joined table.

Comment: @JohnSaunders . . . Assuming that the index resides in memory.

Comment: No, I'm referring to included columns (if that's the right word). The data from the joined table would be _in_ the index.